# Classification using movie review corpus in NLTK/Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, corpus

I'm looking to do some classification in the vein of [NLTK Chapter 6](http://nltk.org/book/ch06.html). The book seems to skip a step in creating the categories, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have my script here with the response following. My issues primarily stem from the first part -- category creation based upon directory names. Some other questions on here have used filenames (i.e. `pos_1.txt` and `neg_1.txt`), but I would prefer to create directories I could dump files into.

```
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

reviews = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('./nltk_data/corpora/movie_reviews', r'(\w+)/*.txt', cat_pattern=r'/(\w+)/.txt')
reviews.categories()
['pos', 'neg']

documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
            for category in movie_reviews.categories()
            for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

all_words=nltk.FreqDist(
    w.lower() 
    for w in movie_reviews.words() 
    if w.lower() not in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english') and w.lower() not in  string.punctuation)
word_features = all_words.keys()[:100]

def document_features(document): 
    document_words = set(document) 
    features = {}
    for word in word_features:
        features['contains(%s)' % word] = (word in document_words)
    return features
print document_features(movie_reviews.words('pos/11.txt'))

featuresets = [(document_features(d), c) for (d,c) in documents]
train_set, test_set = featuresets[100:], featuresets[:100]
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

print nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
classifier.show_most_informative_features(5)
```

This returns:

```
File "test.py", line 38, in <module>
    for w in movie_reviews.words()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.py", line 184, in words
    self, self._resolve(fileids, categories))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.py", line 91, in words
    in self.abspaths(fileids, True, True)])

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.py", line 421, in concat
    raise ValueError('concat() expects at least one object!')

ValueError: concat() expects at least one object!
```

---------UPDATE-------------
Thanks alvas for your detailed answer! I have two questions, however.

1. Is it possible to grab the category from the filename as I was attempting to do? I was hoping to do it in the same vein as the `review_pos.txt` method, only grabbing the `pos` from the folder name rather than the file name.
2. I ran your code and am experiencing a syntax error on

   `train_set =[({i:(i in tokens) for i in word_features}, tag) for tokens,tag in
   documents[:numtrain]] 
   test_set = [({i:(i in tokens) for i in
   word_features}, tag) for tokens,tag in documents[numtrain:]]`

with the carrot under the first `for`. I'm a beginner Python user and I'm not familiar enough with that bit of syntax to try to toubleshoot it.

----UPDATE 2----
Error is

```
File "review.py", line 17
  for i in word_features}, tag)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
```

Comment: I would prefer to use my way to extract the category for each file. But you can eat-your-own-dog-food (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food). About the syntax error, can you post the error shown on the console?

Comment: deleted - added to original

Comment: are you using py2.7 and above? it seems like the syntax is failing because of dict comprehension

Comment: Make sure you use cross validations [cross validation example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) for splitting your data to training and testing set, it's the appropriate way to split your data.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the tutorial on chapter 6 is aim for a basic knowledge for students and from there, the students should build on it by exploring what's available in NLTK and what's not. So let's go through the problems one at a time.

Firstly, the way to get 'pos' / 'neg' documents through the directory is most probably the right thing to do, since the corpus was organized that way.

```
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews as mr
from collections import defaultdict

documents = defaultdict(list)

for i in mr.fileids():
    documents[i.split('/')[0]].append(i)

print documents['pos'][:10] # first ten pos reviews.
print
print documents['neg'][:10] # first ten neg reviews.
```

[out]:

```
['pos/cv000_29590.txt', 'pos/cv001_18431.txt', 'pos/cv002_15918.txt', 'pos/cv003_11664.txt', 'pos/cv004_11636.txt', 'pos/cv005_29443.txt', 'pos/cv006_15448.txt', 'pos/cv007_4968.txt', 'pos/cv008_29435.txt', 'pos/cv009_29592.txt']

['neg/cv000_29416.txt', 'neg/cv001_19502.txt', 'neg/cv002_17424.txt', 'neg/cv003_12683.txt', 'neg/cv004_12641.txt', 'neg/cv005_29357.txt', 'neg/cv006_17022.txt', 'neg/cv007_4992.txt', 'neg/cv008_29326.txt', 'neg/cv009_29417.txt']
```

Alternatively, I like a list of tuples where the first is element is the **list of words in the .txt file** and second is the **category**. And while doing so also remove the stopwords and punctuations:

```
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews as mr
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')
documents = [([w for w in mr.words(i) if w.lower() not in stop and w.lower() not in string.punctuation], i.split('/')[0]) for i in mr.fileids()]
```

Next is the error at `FreqDist(for w in movie_reviews.words() ...)`. There is nothing wrong with your code, just that you should try to use namespace (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace#Use_in_common_languages). The following code:

```
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews as mr
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
stop = stopwords.words('english')

all_words = FreqDist(w.lower() for w in mr.words() if w.lower() not in stop and w.lower() not in string.punctuation)

print all_words
```

**[outputs]:**

```
<FreqDist: 'film': 9517, 'one': 5852, 'movie': 5771, 'like': 3690, 'even': 2565, 'good': 2411, 'time': 2411, 'story': 2169, 'would': 2109, 'much': 2049, ...>
```

Since the above code prints the `FreqDist` correctly, the error seems like you do not have the files in `nltk_data/` directory.

The fact that you have `fic/11.txt` suggests that you're using some older version of the NLTK or NLTK corpora. Normally the `fileids` in `movie_reviews`, starts with either `pos`/`neg` then a slash then the filename and finally `.txt` , e.g. `pos/cv001_18431.txt`.

So I think, maybe you should redownload the files with:

```
$ python
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

Then make sure that the movie review corpus is properly downloaded under the corpora tab:

[image: MR dl]

Back to the code, looping through all the words in the movie review corpus seems redundant if you already have all the words filtered in your documents, so i would rather do this to extract all featureset:

```
word_features = FreqDist(chain(*[i for i,j in documents]))
word_features = word_features.keys()[:100]

featuresets = [({i:(i in tokens) for i in word_features}, tag) for tokens,tag in documents]
```

Next, splitting the train/test by features is okay but i think it's better to use documents, so instead of this:

```
featuresets = [({i:(i in tokens) for i in word_features}, tag) for tokens,tag in documents]
train_set, test_set = featuresets[100:], featuresets[:100]
```

I would recommend this instead:

```
numtrain = int(len(documents) * 90 / 100)
train_set = [({i:(i in tokens) for i in word_features}, tag) for tokens,tag in documents[:numtrain]]
test_set = [({i:(i in tokens) for i in word_features}, tag) for tokens,tag in documents[numtrain:]]
```

Then feed the data into the classifier and voila! So here's the code without the comments and walkthrough:

```
import string
from itertools import chain

from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews as mr
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier as nbc
import nltk

stop = stopwords.words('english')
documents = [([w for w in mr.words(i) if w.lower() not in stop and w.lower() not in string.punctuation], i.split('/')[0]) for i in mr.fileids()]

word_features = FreqDist(chain(*[i for i,j in documents]))
word_features = word_features.keys()[:100]

numtrain = int(len(documents) * 90 / 100)
train_set = [({i:(i in tokens) for i in word_features}, tag) for tokens,tag in documents[:numtrain]]
test_set = [({i:(i in tokens) for i in word_features}, tag) for tokens,tag in documents[numtrain:]]

classifier = nbc.train(train_set)
print nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
classifier.show_most_informative_features(5)
```

**[out]:**

```
0.655
Most Informative Features
                     bad = True              neg : pos    =      2.0 : 1.0
                  script = True              neg : pos    =      1.5 : 1.0
                   world = True              pos : neg    =      1.5 : 1.0
                 nothing = True              neg : pos    =      1.5 : 1.0
                     bad = False             pos : neg    =      1.5 : 1.0
```

Comment: I got it. But one strange result I am getting in this is that the Naive Bayes result is giving the answer as 0,16 to 0.17 which I find really strange. Any possible reason why this is happening?

Comment: alvas I tried the same code. However i get only 0,16 why ?