# Classification using NLTK corpus of movie reviews

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I try to create my own corpus for sentiment analysis of tweets (whether they are positive or negative).

I'm first trying the existing NLTK movie-review corpus.
However, if I'm using this code:

```
import string
from itertools import chain

from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews as mr
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier as nbc
import nltk

stop = stopwords.words('english')
documents = [([w for w in mr.words(i) if w.lower() not in stop and w.lower() not in string.punctuation], i.split('/')[0]) for i in mr.fileids()]

word_features = FreqDist(chain(*[i for i,j in documents]))
word_features = word_features.keys()[:100]

numtrain = int(len(documents) * 90 / 100)
train_set = [({i:(i in tokens) for i in word_features}, tag) for tokens,tag in documents[:numtrain]]
test_set = [({i:(i in tokens) for i in word_features}, tag) for tokens,tag in documents[numtrain:]]

classifier = nbc.train(train_set)
print nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
classifier.show_most_informative_features(5)
```

Im receiving output:

```
0.31
Most Informative Features
               uplifting = True              pos : neg    =      5.9 : 1.0
               wednesday = True              pos : neg    =      3.7 : 1.0
             controversy = True              pos : neg    =      3.4 : 1.0
                  shocks = True              pos : neg    =      3.0 : 1.0
                  catchy = True              pos : neg    =      2.6 : 1.0
```

Instead of the expected output (see [Classification using movie review corpus in NLTK/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107075/classification-using-movie-review-corpus-in-nltk-python) ):

```
0.655
Most Informative Features
                     bad = True              neg : pos    =      2.0 : 1.0
                  script = True              neg : pos    =      1.5 : 1.0
                   world = True              pos : neg    =      1.5 : 1.0
                 nothing = True              neg : pos    =      1.5 : 1.0
                     bad = False             pos : neg    =      1.5 : 1.0
```

I'm using exactly the same code as in the other StackOverflow page, my NLTK (and theirs) is up to date and I also have the most recent movie-reviews corpus. Anyone with an idea what's going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: better once you see what is the length of your corpus.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the below line is making difference:

```
word_features = word_features.keys()[:100]
```

`word_features` is a dict(Counter more precise) object and `keys()` method return values in a arbitrary order so the list of features in your training set is different from the list of features in initial post.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Comment: I Don't think that's the problem, because every time I run this code on different computers, I always get the same results (accuracy 0.31 &  same most informative features)

Comment: keys()' are arbitrary but not random and some variations are implementation specific. If I run the code from a Linux box  I can have different results then running same code on a Win box.