# NaiveBayes Classification in NLTK using python

Tags: python, nltk, naivebayes

I have the following datasets...
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l9nJ.png)

I have load the data using this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
input_file = "C:/Users/User/Documents/R/exp.csv"
df =  pd.read_csv(input_file, header = 0)
```

Now, I am trying to do this...

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(labeled_featuresets)
```

How can i reach there ?

Comment: Why do you read in the data with `header=0`? Apparently, the data *do* have a header.

Comment: I don't know. I found it searching and have no idea why it was used there.

Comment: To me this sounds like you should be working through some tutorials on Python and probably Pandas. First you need to understand the code you pasted and try to build a bridge between the two fragments yourself. Then come back here if you have a more specific question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107075/classification-using-movie-review-corpus-in-nltk-python ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on NLTK and it's workings with their [online tutorial](http://www.nltk.org/book/).

Specifically, you should look into features and classifiers, both of which can be found in [Chapter 6](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html).

Features are simply functions that return some value based on an input, so you can build these functions around the data format of Pandas.