# How to create a dictionary from zipped lists or loop

Tags: python, dictionary, zip, nltk

I am trying to create a dictionary to use for NLP, where the final output should be something like `[{text: "blah blah blah"}, "positive"]`

But when I try to create the dictionary of `"text: blah blah blah"`, even though I'm dealing with a list, the output I get is only one entry long.

Here is the setup code.

```
training_text = []
training_tag = []
with open("training.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as csvfile:
    list_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in list_reader:
        text=row[0]
        tag=row[1]
        training_text.append(text)
        training_tag.append(tag)

training_text_stem = []

for doc in training_text[1:]: #skip first row, which is header 
    #tokenize text
    tok = nltk.word_tokenize(doc)
    text = nltk.Text(tok)

    #normalize words
    words = [w.lower() for w in text if w.isalpha()]

    #build vocabulary
    vocab = sorted(set(words)) 

    #remove stopwords
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    stopwords = stopwords.words('english')
    vocab_redux = [w for w in vocab if w not in stopwords]

    #stemming to reduce topically similar words to their root
    from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
    p_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    vocab_stem = [p_stemmer.stem(i) for i in vocab_redux]

    training_text_stem.append(vocab_stem)
```

This is where it's falling apart. I've tried it 2 ways, as a Dict-Zip comprehension, and as a for loop. In both cases, the output is just one entry, as opposed to the whole list.

```
key = ['text']*len(training_text_stem)    
training_dictionary = dict(zip(training_text_stem, key))
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slZtg.png)

```
def makeadictionary(document):
    dictionarylist = []
    for doc in document:
        dictionarylist.append({'text': doc})
        return(dictionarylist)

makeadictionary(training_text_stem)
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nyvL.png)

Comment: Do you want a list with a dictionary in it, or do you want a dictionary mapping `"blah blah blah: "positive""`

Comment: I'd like the latter, but I need to have a separate entry for each document in my training set, so I assumed I needed a list of dictionaries. Was that a correct assumption? My understanding of this process (machine learning) is that I need to construct a feature set, which in this case is "blah blah blah: text" with some assigned label, either "positive" or "negative. This feature set is then entered into the NLTK classifier.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107075/classification-using-movie-review-corpus-in-nltk-python