# Tagging each word with True before passing it to the classifier in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, naivebayes

Can anyone help me in understanding the purpose of `format(sentence)` function in the code below except for ignoring the repeating words? Why the `True` added after each word?

```
{'I': True, 'Oh': True, 'yes': True, 'got': True, 'that': True, '.': True}
{'?': True, 'mad': True, 'Are': True, 'you': True}
```

Can we pass the sentence to classifier without tagging the `True` after each word?

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier

def format(sentence):
    return {word:True for word in word_tokenize(sentence)} 

s0= 'Oh yes. I got that'  
s1= 'Are you mad?'  

trainData = [[formatMe(s0),'pos'],[formatMe(s1),'neg']]
model = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainData)
print(model.classify(format(s1)))
```

Code credits: [Tutorial at Slide Share](http://www.slideshare.net/waitingkuo0527/sentiment-analysisbynltk)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107075/classification-using-movie-review-corpus-in-nltk-python

Comment: @alvas Link is not working. Giving `sorry this content isn't available at the moment`