# Python , classify module in NLTK

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, nltk

I am taking the ML course at udacity and have the following problem

```
>>> import nltk    
>>> from nltk import classify    
>>> clf = classify(feat_train,lab_train)   
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "(stdin)", line 1, in (module)    
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`
```

Comment: Nobody wants to read code from a screenshot. Just cut-and-paste the text, enclosed in \```triple-backticks``` and it will be formatted `mono-space`.

Comment: What is your question? . I am not sure what you are trying to do. `classify` is a package.

Comment: I am trying to train a classifier using training features and labels

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107075/classification-using-movie-review-corpus-in-nltk-python