# Categorizing data using sentiment analysis

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, spacy

I have a text file which has a data as below. There are many such lines but not of the same pattern

```
Celina is acting as assistant to John, M.D.
```

I want to categorize Celina as assistant and John as M.D.

I need guidance on what would be the approach to handle such problems?
Is it Sentiment Analysis?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107075/classification-using-movie-review-corpus-in-nltk-python/21126594

Answer (score 3):

It is not categorizing nor sentiment analysis. *Semantic role labeling* or *information extraction* fields solve the problem you are addressing.

I kindly suggest you to look at those pages for starters: https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/22.pdf and https://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html